# JS search using keyup event on input tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have few `div` elements with different text content and one `input` tag.

```
<input id="search" type="text"/>

<div class="list>
  <div id="el"> red </div>
  <div id="el"> blue </div>
  <div id="el"> red green </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to get something like this:
if `div`'s `textContent` is equal to `input.value` this `div` is displayed. Else, it's hidden.

**Example:**

```
input.value = "red"
/* "red" and "red green" are displayed, "blue" is hidden */
```

**My JS code:**

```js
var search = document.getElementById("search");
var el = document.getElementById("el");

search.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
  if(search.value == el.textContent){
    el.style.display = "block"}
  else{
    el.style.display = "none"}})
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text"/>

<div class="list">
  <div id="el"> red </div>
  <div id="el"> blue </div>
  <div id="el"> red green </div>
  
 </div>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to assign the same `id` to multiple items. Instead use `class`.

See below for a working solution:

```js
var search = document.getElementById("search");
var els = document.querySelectorAll(".el");

search.addEventListener("keyup", function() {

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
    if (el.textContent.trim().indexOf(search.value) > -1)
      el.style.display = 'block';
    else el.style.display = 'none';
  });

});
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" />

<div class="list">
  <div class="el">red</div>
  <div class="el">blue</div>
  <div class="el">red green</div>

</div>
```

Here's the solution for regardless of where the input is located, as long as it is space delimited (just in case):

```js
var search = document.getElementById("search");
var els = document.querySelectorAll(".el");

search.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
    var values = search.value.split(' ');
    var display = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if(el.textContent.trim().indexOf(values[i]) === -1)
        display = false;
    }
    
    el.style.display = display ? 'block' : 'none';
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" />

<div class="list">
  <div class="el">red</div>
  <div class="el">blue</div>
  <div class="el">red green</div>

</div>
```

Comment: no problem. By the way, I'm assuming you still want an input of 'green red' to display the 'red green' `<div>`? I'm working on improving the solution for that now.

Comment: I can accept in 3 mins :) Thanks again but it's not necessary